# Installing Pocketsphinx on Windows 10

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx, windows-10-desktop

I am trying to install pocketsphinx on Windows 10. I have downloaded pocketsphinx and sphinxbase, built them both, and put sphinxbase.dll into the pocketsphinx bin. However when I copy and paste the command

`bin\Debug\Win32\pocketsphinx_continuous.exe -inmic yes -hmm model\en-us\en-us -lm model\en-us\en-us.lm.bin -dict model\en-us\cmudict-en-us.dict`

into the command prompt (following the CMU Sphinx directions per https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx/#windows) the last few lines of output look like this:

```
INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='batch', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: acmod.c(162): Using subvector specification 0-12/13-25/26-38
INFO: mdef.c(518): Reading model definition: model/en-us/en-us/mdef
INFO: mdef.c(531): Found byte-order mark BMDF, assuming this is a binary mdef file
INFO: bin_mdef.c(336): Reading binary model definition: model/en-us/en-us/mdef
INFO: bin_mdef.c(516): 42 CI-phone, 137053 CD-phone, 3 emitstate/phone, 126 CI-sen, 5126 Sen, 29324 Sen-Seq
INFO: tmat.c(149): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: model/en-us/en-us/transition_matrices
```

However I do not get the Ready... or Listening... prompt that I have seen other people get to test out the software. I seem to get much less output than others as well (nothing about dict.c or ms_gauden.c etc.) Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this problem, check the Visual Studio Runtime Library property is set to Multi-threaded DLL (/MD), especially if you are running a newer version of Visual Studio. To check this, in Visual Studio go to:

> Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library

to verify/change this setting. You may have to redownload sphinxbase and pocketsphinx before doing this. Build the .sln only after changing this setting.

Comment: Hello, glad you found the solution, you can mark your answer, it will help more people with the same problem